# How do you perform conditional validations in Rails of an attribute that depends on another attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, conditional-statements

I have this field `:endpoint` that I need to validate differently based on the presence of another attribute (`:subscribed_events`).

I need `:endpoint` to:

- Be allowed to be blank in the absence of `:subscribed_events`
- Have a valid format (`http_url`) if it's not `nil`
- Be present and with a valid format (`http_url`) if `:subscribed_events` is present

I've written something like this:

```
validates :endpoint, http_url: { allow_blank: true }, presence: true, if: :subscribed_events?
```

But the `http_url` format is only validated in the presence of `:subscribed_events`, otherwise it'll allow anything such as "hello".

Can I make `http_url` validation non dependant of `:subscribed_events` and validate all of the conditions described above in a single line or do I have to write different validations?

Comment: Writing it in a single line sounds very complex. I would consider approaching the problem from how you write some that can be tested and read by others instead of just maximizing terseness.

Answer (score 1):

You can write custom validators. Here is a starting point for you:

```
validate :endpoint_validator

def endpoint_validator
  unless subscribed_events.blank?
    if endpoint.blank?
      errors.add(:enpoint, "can't be blank if subscribed_events is blank")
      return false
    end
  end

  # http_url validation here
  # other code here

  return true
end
```

Or, you can create one function for each field you want to custom validate. It's actually more organized.